# Is that possible to know if element exists inside an array without looping through the array?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of elements with the same structure each.
Here's an example :

```
<?php
    $arr =
        [
            [
                "el_name" => "abcd",
                "el_data" => "raw_dataè_15264df156g18df",
            ],
            [
                "el_name" => "efgh",
                "el_data" => "raw_data_sd25g",
            ],
            [
                "el_name" => "ijkl",
                "el_data" => "raw_data_dfdfgn48",
            ],
            [
                "el_name" => "mnop",
                "el_data" => "raw_data_²545",
            ],
        ];
    
    $new_el = [
        "el_name" => "efgh",
        "el_data" => "raw_data_sd25g",
    ];
```

I want to add `$new_el` only if it's not already present in `$arr`. It'd be handy if php had a `array_element_exists()` function ;-)

For the sake of the question I tried this:

```
$exists = false;
foreach($arr as $el) {
    $equal=true;
    foreach(array_keys($el) as $key) {
        if(isset($new_el[$key]) && $new_el[$key] === $el[$key]) {
            null;
            //equality
        } else {
            $equal = false;
        }
    }
    if($equal === true) {
        $exists = true;
        break;
    }
}
if($exists === true ) {
    echo '$new_el already exists in $arr' . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo '$new_el doesn\'t still exists in $arr' . PHP_EOL;
    $arr[] = $new_el;
}
```

Do you think there are more efficient, 'simpler' ways ?...

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.

```php
in_array($new_el, $arr);
```

returns `true`.

Comment: my bad! It works and it's the built-in function I was looking for

Comment: this one perfect. deleted mine. +1

Answer (score 1):

```php
function array_element_exists($new_el,$arr){
    $found = array_filter($arr, function($arr) use ($new_el) {
        return $arr['el_name'] === $new_el['el_name'] && 
            $arr['el_data'] === $new_el['el_data'];
    });
    return $found;
}

  
$exsist = ["el_name" => "efgh","el_data" => "raw_data_sd25g"];
$notExsist = ["el_name" => "newName","el_data" => "newData",];

//will not be added since it is already exist
if (!array_element_exists($exsist,$arr)) {
    $arr[] = $exsist;
}

//will be added because it is new and not exist in `$arr`
if (!array_element_exists($notExsist,$arr)) {
    $arr[] = $notExsist;
}
```

Comment: seems perfect... !